# Android : Remove LocationListener

Tags: android, gps

I have following code to get User Location using GPS.(Code is working fine)
But My problem is that When I close Program (Press back button) It generates error message 
**The Application ...... has stopped work .........Please try again.**  .
I think that I have to remove listener for that I have use **removeUpdates()** method in **onDestroy()** then also same error message is generate.
 
How I can resolve It.
My code :

```
public class Location_AddressActivity extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    TextView txt_logitude;
    TextView txt_latitude;
    TextView txt_address;
    LocationListener mlocListener;
    LocationManager mlocManager;
    Geocoder geocoder;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {       

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        txt_logitude=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_logitude);
        txt_latitude=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_latitude);
        txt_address=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_address);
        geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.ENGLISH);
        txt_latitude.setText("");
        txt_logitude.setText("");
        txt_address.setText("");
        mlocManager= (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();
        mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);
    }
    public  void onDestroy()
    {
        mlocManager.removeUpdates(mlocListener);
    }
    class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener
    {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            double latitude=location.getLatitude();
            double longitude=location.getLongitude();
            txt_latitude.setText(new Double(latitude).toString());
            txt_logitude.setText(new Double(longitude).toString());
            try {
                List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);              
                if(addresses != null) {
                    Address returnedAddress = addresses.get(0);
                    StringBuilder strReturnedAddress = new StringBuilder("Address:\n");
                    for(int i=0; i<returnedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                        strReturnedAddress.append(returnedAddress.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
                    }
                    txt_address.setText(strReturnedAddress.toString());
                }
                else{
                    txt_address.setText("No Address returned!");
                }
            } 
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                txt_address.setText(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            txt_address.setText("GPS Disable");
        }
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            txt_address.setText("GPS Enable");      
        }           
    }   
}
```

Thanks..

Comment: please provide crash logs.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have removed the call to `super.onDestroy` in your `onDestroy()` of Your Activity. Just change that Code as below and give a try.

```
public  void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        mlocManager.removeUpdates(mlocListener);
    }
```

I hope removeUpdates() not creating any issues for you.

Answer (score 2):

```
location.removeUpdates(your listener);
```

this is the correct way to remove location listener

Answer (score -1):

I guess when you are customizing the Location Listener by implementing the LocationListener class you should create instance of MyLocationListener , here you are registering the Super class and you are also customizing it .that doesn't make sense .

Try MyLocationListener mLocationListener above onCreate and use that object for request and remove update.